# Reproducing the Periodic Table of Arguments in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have to draw the [Periodic Table of Arguments by Jean Wagemans](https://periodic-table-of-arguments.org/) in LaTeX. In practice, the result should be something like [this](https://rhetoricchecking.files.wordpress.com/2018/05/schermafdruk-2018-05-14-22-26-21.png).

[image] I tried to use the source code of examples of the classic Periodic Table of Chemical Elements but in vain. So, I tried myself to write the code from scratch. My main problem regards the alignment between the element squares, which are aligned on the text in the middle of the square, instead of the square itself.

This is my output of the alpha quadrant:

[image: alpha quadrant]

This is how it should be:

[image]

Can you help me to obtain a result closer to the original? This is my source code:

```
  \documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
  % -----------------------------
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[square/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4}]
  % 1 alpha FF Sig
  \node at (0.2,0.2) [square, draw, anchor=south west, minimum size=2cm, fill=blue!50] (Sig) {\verb!Sig!};
  \node at (1,0.5) [draw=blue!50] {\tiny{from sign}}; % text inside Sig
  \node [square, draw, minimum size=2cm, align=left, fill=blue!50, above of=Sig] (Cau) {\verb!Cau!};
  \node [square, draw, minimum size=2cm, fill=blue!50, above of=Cau] (Ef) {\verb!Ef!};
  \node [square, draw, minimum size=2cm, fill=blue!50, above of=Ef](Cor){\verb!Cor!};
  % 1 alpha VF
  \node [square, draw, minimum size=2cm, fill=green!50, right of=Sig,](Cr){\verb!Cr!};
  % 1 alpha VV
  \node [square, draw, minimum size=2cm, fill=yellow!50, right of=Cr](St){\verb!St!};
  \node [square, draw, minimum size=2cm, fill=yellow!50, above of=St](Ax){\verb!Ax!};
 % 1 alpha PV
 \node [square, draw, minimum size=2cm, fill=purple!50, right  of=St](Pr){\verb!Pr!};
 \node [square, draw, minimum size=2cm, fill=orange!50, right of=Pr](De){\verb!De!};
 % Axes
 \draw [dotted,thick] (-7,0) -- (7,0);
 \draw [dotted,thick] (0,-7) -- (0,7);
  % The grid -- comment when ready
 \draw[step=.5cm,gray,very thin] (-7,-7) grid (7,7);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

I would like to retain the feature "above of" and "right of" as it makes the code easier to maintain when there will be new version of the Period Table of Arguments.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Nice first question :)

Comment: Thank you! Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: No, sorry, I can't help you. But we have some outstanding Ti*k*Z experts in this site. I'm sure you'll have an answer very soon :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An option using a drawing structure definition to reuse a drawing with better control of positions of the text nodes inside the box, and avoid to repeating writing all the commands for each box; then helped with the positioning library you could put the next box next to other by certain distance, in all cases 0, but you can complete all the drawing with less lines of code jus defining the distance below, above, right or left from another box and the combination like:

`\Arg[Box_Name][Box_desc][Box_type](below right=12pt and 0 of Another_box_name)(color)`

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usetikzlibrary[positioning]
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        font=\sffamily
    ]
    %Defining a drawing structure
    \def\Arg[#1][#2][#3](#4)(#5){%1:Node name and label 2:description 3:type 4:position relative using positioning 5:color
        \node[
            line width=1pt,
            draw,
            #4,
            fill=#5,
            rectangle,
            inner sep=0,
            outer sep=0,
            minimum size=2.5cm
        ](#1){};
        \draw[every node/.append style={anchor=west}]
            (#1.center)++(-1,0) node {\LARGE\bfseries #1}
            (#1.center)++(-1,0.9) node {\scriptsize\bfseries #3}
            (#1.center)++(-1,-0.3) node[anchor= north west,align=left,font=\scriptsize\bfseries\sffamily]{ #2};
        }

    %Start drawing the thing...
    \definecolor{mycyan}{HTML}{A5C4E4}
    \definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{B2D096}
    \definecolor{myyellow}{HTML}{F9DA79}
    \definecolor{mypurple}{HTML}{B39BCD}
    \definecolor{myorange}{HTML}{EBB58B}

    \Arg[Cor][from correlation][1 pre FF]()(mycyan)
    \Arg[Ef][from effect][1 pre FF](below=0 of Cor)(mycyan)
    \Arg[Cau][from cause][1 pre FF](below=0 of Ef)(mycyan)
    \Arg[Sig][from sign][1 pre FF](below=0 of Cau)(mycyan)
    \Arg[Cr][from criterion][1 pre VF](right=0 of Sig)(mygreen)
    \Arg[St][from standard][1 pre W](right=0 of Cr)(myyellow)
    \Arg[Ax][from axiologic \\ argument][1 pre W](above=0 of St)(myyellow)
    \Arg[Pr][from pragmatic \\ argument][1 pre PF](right=0 of St)(mypurple)
    \Arg[De][from deontic \\ argument][1 pre PV](right=0 of Pr)(myorange)
    \Arg[Ev][from evaluation \\ argument][1 pre PV](above=0 of De)(myorange)
    %Fron the other quadrant-
    \Arg[Em][from emotion][2 pre PP](below right=12pt and 0 of De)(myorange!70!red)

    \draw[dash pattern=on 5.5pt off 3pt,ultra thick,black!60]
        (De.south east) ++(2.5cm,-6pt) coordinate (axisX)
        (Cor.north west) ++ (-6pt,0) coordinate (axisY)
        (axisX -| axisY) edge (axisX) edge (axisY); % Using edges to obtain corner with dash line on.

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 24):

You are loading the positioning library, but not using it. Once one changes the syntax, it works out fine. In more detail, e.g. `above of=Sig` has to become in positioning syntax `above=<distance> of Sig`. I acknowledge a [comment by Fato39](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450102/reproducing-the-periodic-table-of-arguments-in-latex/450110?noredirect=1#comment1131370_450110) urging me to do that. This is the only change I did. There are by now some more sophisticated proposals here, among which IMHO [Max' matrix approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/450112/121799) may be the most convenient, closely followed by [Zarko's chains](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/450114/121799), and of course no one has as nice colors as [J. Leon V](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/450134/121799). Nox had the [very first answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/450109/121799), and it is always easier to write something better after one sees what others did.

```
  \documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
  % -----------------------------
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[square/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4}]
  % 1 alpha FF Sig
  \node at (0.2,0.2) [square, draw, anchor=south west, minimum size=2cm, fill=blue!50] (Sig) {\verb!Sig!};
  \node at (1,0.5) [draw=blue!50] {\tiny{from sign}}; % text inside Sig
  \node [square, draw, minimum size=2cm, align=left, fill=blue!50, above=0pt of Sig] (Cau) {\verb!Cau!};
  \node [square, draw, minimum size=2cm, fill=blue!50, above=0pt of Cau] (Ef) {\verb!Ef!};
  \node [square, draw, minimum size=2cm, fill=blue!50, above=0pt of Ef](Cor){\verb!Cor!};
  % 1 alpha VF
  \node [square, draw, minimum size=2cm, fill=green!50, right=0pt of Sig,](Cr){\verb!Cr!};
  % 1 alpha VV
  \node [square, draw, minimum size=2cm, fill=yellow!50, right=0pt of Cr](St){\verb!St!};
  \node [square, draw, minimum size=2cm, fill=yellow!50, above=0pt of St](Ax){\verb!Ax!};
 % 1 alpha PV
 \node [square, draw, minimum size=2cm, fill=purple!50, right=0pt of St](Pr){\verb!Pr!};
 \node [square, draw, minimum size=2cm, fill=orange!50, right=0pt of Pr](De){\verb!De!};
 % Axes
 \draw [dotted,thick] (-7,0) -- (7,0);
 \draw [dotted,thick] (0,-7) -- (0,7);
  % The grid -- comment when ready
 \draw[step=.5cm,gray,very thin] (-7,-7) grid (7,7);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Further improvements:

1. Corrected the width by taking into account thr `outer sep`. (This is not really necessary.)
2. Used labels to place the small texts. Specifically, defined styles `label A` (above) and `label B` (below) for that.
3. Simplified the other styles to avoid unnecessary repetition.
4. Set the `node distance` to `-\pgflinewidth` in order to have the same thickness of the border everywhere, and also to spare you from typing `0pt`.

Here is the improved code.

```
  \documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
  % -----------------------------
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[square/.style={minimum
  size=2cm-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep},
  draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4},
  label B/.style={label={[anchor=north west,font=\tiny\sffamily,yshift=16pt,
  xshift=3pt,scale=0.75,align=left]below left:#1}},
  label A/.style={label={[anchor=north,font=\tiny\sffamily,yshift=-2pt,scale=0.75]above:#1}},
  blue square/.style={square,fill=blue!50,label A=1 pre FF},
  yellow square/.style={square,fill=yellow!50,label A=1 pre W},
  orange square/.style={square,fill=orange!50,label A=1 pre PV},
  node distance=-\pgflinewidth
  ]
  % 1 alpha FF Sig
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
  \node [above right= of O,blue square,label B=from sign] (Sig) {\verb!Sig!};
  \node [blue square,above= of Sig,label B=from cause] (Cau) {\verb!Cau!};
  \node [blue square,above= of Cau,label B=from effect] (Ef) {\verb!Ef!};
  \node [blue square,above= of Ef,label B=from correlation](Cor){\verb!Cor!};
  % 1 alpha VF
  \node [square,fill=green!50,right= of Sig,label A=1 pre VF,label B=from
  criterion](Cr){\verb!Cr!};
  % 1 alpha VV
  \node [yellow square,right= of Cr,label B=from standard](St){\verb!St!};
  \node [yellow square,above= of St,label B=axiolic\\ argument](Ax){\verb!Ax!};
 % 1 alpha PV
 \node [square,fill=purple!50,right= of St,label B=pragmatic\\ argument,
 label A=pre PF](Pr){\verb!Pr!};
 \node [orange square,right= of Pr,label B=deontic\\ argument](De){\verb!De!};
 \node [orange square,above= of De,label B=from evaluation](Ev){\verb!Ev!};
 % Axes
 \draw [dotted,thick] (-7,0) -- (7,0);
 \draw [dotted,thick] (0,-7) -- (0,7);
  % The grid -- comment when ready
 \draw[step=.5cm,gray,very thin] (-7,-7) grid (7,7);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest explicitly pointing out the changes you made in the code before the code block. Since the change is small, I couldn't notice it right away, not knowing the correct solution.

Comment: @Fato39 Sorry, I do not understand? Do you mean the difference in syntax between with and without `positioning`?

Comment: I mean that it would make it easier understand to highlight the change from: `above of=Sig` to `above=0pt of Sig`. At least that's how I understand you meant by "(not) using the `positioning` library"?

Comment: +1, for the speed in responding and sacrificing to do more complex things, thanks for mentioning my option only for the colors T_T... mmmI just remembered that I had already voted up...

Answer (score 13):

Altough you already have two very usable answers, I wanted to show an alternative that is (arguably) more readable *and* easier to adjust to future changes. Using Ti*k*z `matrix of nodes`, you can assign styles to certain columns, which is very convenient in such a table. I added a `sub={<text>}`, and `super={<text>}` key that take care of the extra text in the cells.

The code that describes the contents of the table is a lot less cluttered by positioning settings, and only is

```
|[sub={from correlation}]|Cor &                             &                                 &                                 &  \\
|[sub={from effect}]| Ef      &                             &                                 &                                 &  \\
|[sub={from cause}]| Cau      &                             & |[sub={axiologic argument}]| Ax &                                 & |[sub={from evaluation}]| Ev \\
|[sub={from sign}]| Sig       & |[sub={from criterion}]| Cr & |[sub={from standard}]| St      & |[sub={pragmatic argument}]| Pr & |[sub={deontic argument}]| De \\
```

Which results in:

[image]

Note that you could overwrite the additional text above the cells with the `super=` key, for every cell. So the default value is the one specified for the column number, but if for some reason you want a different value for a specific cell, you can simply overwrite it.

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix[
            matrix of nodes,
            column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
            row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
            nodes={
                minimum size=2cm,
                draw,
                anchor=center,
                fill,
                text width=1.8cm,
                inner sep=1mm,
                font=\ttfamily\LARGE,
                align=justify,
            },
            sub/.style={execute at end node={\bgroup\\[-0.65\baselineskip]\tiny #1\egroup}},
            super/.style={execute at begin node={\bgroup\color{black}\footnotesize #1 \\[-0.15\baselineskip]\egroup}},
            column 1/.style={fill=blue!50,  super={1 Pre FF}},
            column 2/.style={fill=green!50, super={1 Pre VF}},
            column 3/.style={fill=yellow!50,super={1 Pre VV}},
            column 4/.style={fill=purple!50,super={1 Pre PF}},
            column 5/.style={fill=orange!50,super={1 Pre PV}},
        ]{
            |[sub={from correlation}]|Cor &                             &                                 &                                 &  \\
            |[sub={from effect}]| Ef      &                             &                                 &                                 &  \\
            |[sub={from cause}]| Cau      &                             & |[sub={axiologic argument}]| Ax &                                 & |[sub={from evaluation}]| Ev \\
            |[sub={from sign}]| Sig       & |[sub={from criterion}]| Cr & |[sub={from standard}]| St      & |[sub={pragmatic argument}]| Pr & |[sub={deontic argument}]| De \\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**
I changed the styles slightly to incorporate the solution for the sub and sup texts by using labels. Credits to marmot and zarko (I'm not sure who was first). I have not finished all arguments, and it's quite late here so there could be some spelling errors in there. *One more edit*: I added a style for the `delta quadrant`. I trust you will be able to finish it:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
    sup/.style={label={[minimum size=0,font=\scriptsize,anchor=north west,shift={(-10mm-0.5\pgflinewidth,-1.5mm)}]#1}},
    sub/.style={label={[minimum size=0,font=\tiny,anchor=north west,shift={(-10mm-0.5\pgflinewidth,-12mm)}]#1}},
    co1/.style={fill=blue!50},
    co2/.style={fill=green!50},
    co3/.style={fill=yellow!50},
    co4/.style={fill=purple!50},
    co5/.style={fill=orange!50},
    co6/.style={fill=red!50},
    my empty cell/.style={minimum size=2cm,fill=none,draw=none},
    table of arguments/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        inner sep=1mm,
        nodes={
            minimum size=2cm,
            draw,
            anchor=center,
            fill,
            text width=1.8cm,
            font=\ttfamily\LARGE,
            align=justify,
        },
    },
    alpha quadrant/.style={
        table of arguments,
        name=alpha,
        matrix anchor=south west,
        co1/.append style={sup={1 Pre FF}},
        co2/.append style={sup={1 Pre VF}},
        co3/.append style={sup={1 Pre VV}},
        co4/.append style={sup={1 Pre PF}},
        co5/.append style={sup={1 Pre PV}},
    },
    beta quadrant/.style={
        table of arguments,
        name=beta,
        matrix anchor=south east,
        co1/.append style={sup={1 Sub FF}},
        co3/.append style={sup={1 Sub VV}},
        co4/.append style={sup={1 Sub PF}},
        co6/.append style={sup={1 Sub PP}},
    },
    gamma quadrant/.style={
        table of arguments,
        name=gamma,
        matrix anchor=north east,
        co2/.append style={sup={2 Sub VF}},
        co3/.append style={sup={2 Sub VV}},
        co4/.append style={sup={2 Sub PF}},
    },
    delta quadrant/.style={
        table of arguments,
        name=delta,
        matrix anchor=north west,
        co2/.append style={sup={2 pre VF}},
        co3/.append style={sup={2 pre VV}},
        co4/.append style={sup={2 pre PF}},
        co5/.append style={sup={2 pre PV}},
        co6/.append style={sup={2 pre PP}},
    },
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix[alpha quadrant]{
            |[co1,sub={from correlation}]|Cor &                                 &                                     &                                     &                                   & \\
            |[co1,sub={from effect}]| Ef      &                                 &                                     &                                     &                                   & \\
            |[co1,sub={from cause}]| Cau      &                                 & |[co3,sub={axiologic argument}]| Ax &                                     & |[co5,sub={from evaluation}]| Ev  & \\
            |[co1,sub={from sign}]| Sig       & |[co2,sub={from criterion}]| Cr & |[co3,sub={from standard}]| St      & |[co4,sub={pragmatic argument}]| Pr & |[co5,sub={deontic argument}]| De & \\
        };
        \matrix[beta quadrant]{
                                               &                   &                                &                               &                   & |[co1,sub={case to case}]| Cas \\
                                               &                   &                                & |[co3,sub={a minore}]| Min    &                   & |[co1,sub={from example}]| Exa\\
                                               &                   & |[co4,sub={from parallel}]| Pa & |[co3,sub={a manore}]| Ma     &                   & |[co1,sub={from genus}]| G \\
            |[co6,sub={from comparison}]| Comp & |[my empty cell]| & |[co4,sub={from equality}]| Eq & |[co3,sub={from analogy}]| An & |[my empty cell]| & |[co1,sub={from similarity}]| Sim \\
        };
        \matrix[gamma quadrant]{
            |[co4,sub={from consistency}]| Con & |[co3,sub={from opposites}]| O     & |[co2,sub={from tradition}]| T & |[my empty cell]| \\
                                               & |[co3,sub={from disjunctives}]| Di &                                &                   \\
                                               & |[co3,sub={pertitio principi}]| Pe &                                &                   \\
        };
        \matrix[delta quadrant]{
            |[my empty cell]| & |[co2,sub={from authority}]| Au & |[co3,sub={from utility}]| U & |[co4,sub={ad baculum}]| Ba & |[co5,sub={from character}]| Ch & |[co6,sub={from emotion}]| Em \\
        };
        \draw[dashed] (0,8) -- (0,-8)
            (-12,0) -- (12,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like a lot your solution, as it takes care of the ratio behind the Periodic Table of Arguments. Is it possible to have the axes and to reproduce all the four quadrants, not just the alpha? See picture above

Comment: @FedericoGobbo I added styles for the `alpha quadrant`, `beta quadrant`, and `gamma quadrant`, I trust you will be able to finish the `delta quadrant` following the example :)

Answer (score 10):

This is a little hacky solution, but it should work, if you create the table from left to right. I corrected the offset of the lines manually and created a `\lastcolor` command that colors the `\nodeabove`s correctly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\cont}[3]{%
  \parbox[t][1.5cm]{1.5cm}{%
    \tiny #2\\[.4cm]%
    \normalsize \texttt{#1}\\[.1cm]%
    \fontsize{3}{5}\selectfont #3}%
}

\newcommand{\lastcolor}{}
\newcommand{\lastbasenode}{}
\newcommand{\lastnode}{}
\newcommand{\lastsup}{}

\newcommand{\basenode}[4]{%
  \renewcommand{\lastcolor}{#4}
  \renewcommand{\lastbasenode}{#1}
  \renewcommand{\lastnode}{#1}
  \renewcommand{\lastsup}{#2}
  \node (rect) at (0.2cm,0.2cm) [draw,
                                 thick,
                                 minimum width=2cm,
                                 minimum height=2cm,
                                 anchor=south west,
                                 fill=\lastcolor,
                                 xshift=-.4pt,
                                 yshift=-.4pt] (#1) {\cont{#1}{#2}{#3}};
}

\newcommand{\nodeabove}[2]{%
  \node (rect) [draw,
                thick,
                minimum width=2cm,
                minimum height=2cm,
                anchor=south west,
                above=of \lastnode.center,
                fill=\lastcolor,
                yshift=-.4pt] (#1) {\cont{#1}{\lastsup}{#2}};
  \renewcommand{\lastnode}{#1}
}

\newcommand{\noderight}[4]{%
  \renewcommand{\lastcolor}{#4}
  \renewcommand{\lastsup}{#2}
  \node (rect) [draw,
                thick,
                minimum width=2cm,
                minimum height=2cm,
                anchor=south west,
                right=of \lastbasenode.center,
                fill=\lastcolor,
                xshift=-.4pt] (#1) {\cont{#1}{\lastsup}{#3}};
  \renewcommand{\lastbasenode}{#1}
  \renewcommand{\lastnode}{#1}
}


% -----------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% 1 alpha FF Sig

\basenode {Sig}{1 pre FF}{from sign}{blue!30}
\nodeabove{Cau}          {from cause}
\nodeabove{Ef}           {from effect}
%
\noderight{Cr}{1 pre VF}{from criterion}{green!30}
%
\noderight{St}{1 pre VV}{from standard}{yellow!50}
\nodeabove{Ef}          {axiologic\\argument}
%
\noderight{Pr}{1 pre PF}{pragmatic\\argument}{purple!20}

\draw [dotted,thick] (-7,0) -- (7,0);
\draw [dotted,thick] (0,-7) -- (0,7);
% The grid -- comment when ready
\draw[step=.5cm,gray,very thin] (-7,-7) grid (7,7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

**edit:** Cleaner code.

Answer (score 8):

**edit (1):**
ups, i didn't load last solution. now corrected ...

oh, one more answer: exploiting library `chains` and common definition of all `square` nodes:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0pt,
  start chain = going above,
square/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{%
        rectangle, draw, semithick,
        fill=#1,
        minimum size=20mm, inner sep=2mm, outer sep=0mm,
        font=\large\sffamily, 
        label={[anchor=north]above:#2},
        label={[anchor=south,yshift=0.5ex]below:#3},
        on chain},
every label/.append style = {%
        label distance=0pt, text depth=0.25ex, align=center,
        font=\footnotesize\sffamily\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}
                        ]
% 1. column, from bottom to top
\node (Sig) [square=blue!30/1 pre FF/from\\ sign]     {Sig};
\node (Cau) [square=blue!30/1 pre FF/from\\ cause]    {Cau};
\node (Ef)  [square=blue!30/1 pre FF/from\\ effect]   {Ef};
\node (Cor) [square=blue!30/1 pre FF/from\\ 
                                     correlation]   {Cor};
% 2. column, from bottom to top
\node (Cr)  [square=olive!30/1 pre VF/from\\ criterion,
             right=of Sig]                          {Cr};
% 3. column, from bottom to top
\node (St)  [square=yellow!30/1 pre W/from\\ standard,
             right=of Cr]                           {St};
\node (Ax)  [square=yellow!30/1 pre W/axiologic\\ 
                                      argument]     {Ax};
% 4. column, from bottom to top
\node (Pr)  [square=purple!30/1 pre PF/pragmatic\\ argument,
             right=of St]                           {Pr};
% 5. column, from bottom to top
\node (De)  [square=orange!30/1 pre PV/deontic\\ argument,
             right=of Pr]                           {De};
\node (Ev)  [square=orange!30/1 pre PV/from\\ 
                                       evaluation]  {Ev};
% Axes
\draw [dotted,thick] ([xshift=-1mm] Cor.north west) |- ([yshift=-1mm] De.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit (2):**
similarly can be drawn "squares" in other quadrants. in this the above code should be devided into two parts:

- first is in `scope` where chains of node going above (`start chain = going above`). it is used in the first and second quadrant)
- first is in `scope` where chains of node going below (`start chain = going below`). it is used in the first and second quadrant)

a not complete example of this approach is:

```
    \documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{chains,
                    positioning}
    % -----------------------------
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 0pt,
    square/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{%
            rectangle, draw, semithick,
            fill=#1,
            minimum size=20mm, inner sep=2mm, outer sep=0mm,
            font=\large\sffamily,
            label={[anchor=north]above:#2},
            label={[anchor=south,yshift=0.5ex]below:#3},
            on chain},
    every label/.append style = {%
            label distance=0pt, text depth=0.25ex, align=center,
            font=\footnotesize\sffamily\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}
                            ]
    \begin{scope}[start chain = going above]
    % RIGHT (first quadrant)
    % 1. column, from bottom to top
    \node (Sig) [square=blue!30/1 pre FF/from\\ sign]     {Sig};
    \node (Cau) [square=blue!30/1 pre FF/from\\ cause]    {Cau};
    \node (Ef)  [square=blue!30/1 pre FF/from\\ effect]   {Ef};
    \node (Cor) [square=blue!30/1 pre FF/from\\
                                         correlation]   {Cor};
    % 2. column, from bottom to top
    \node (Cr)  [square=olive!30/1 pre VF/from\\ criterion,
                 right=of Sig]                          {Cr};
    % 3. column, from bottom to top
    \node (St)  [square=yellow!30/1 pre W/from\\ standard,
                 right=of Cr]                           {St};
    \node (Ax)  [square=yellow!30/1 pre W/axiologic\\
                                          argument]     {Ax};
    % 4. column, from bottom to top
    \node (Pr)  [square=purple!30/1 pre PF/pragmatic\\ argument,
                 right=of St]                           {Pr};
    % 5. column, from bottom to top
    \node (De)  [square=orange!30/1 pre PV/deontic\\ argument,
                 right=of Pr]                           {De};
    \node (Ev)  [square=orange!30/1 pre PV/from\\
                                           evaluation]  {Ev};
    % LEFT (second quadrant)
    % 1. column, from bottom to top
    \node (Sim) [square=blue!30/1 pre FF/from\\ sign,
                 left= 2mm of Sig]                      {Sig};
    \node (G)   [square=blue!30/1 pre FF/from\\ cause]  {G};
    \node (Exa) [square=blue!30/1 pre FF/from\\ effect] {Cas};
    \node (Cas) [square=blue!30/1 pre FF/from\\
                                         correlation]   {Cor};

    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[start chain = going below]
     % 2. column, from top to bottom
    \node (Au)  [square=olive!30/2 pre VF/from\\ authority,
                 below=2mm of Cr]                       {Cr};
    \node (Po)  [square=olive!30/2 pre VF/ad\\
                                          xxxxx]        {Po};
    \node (Comm)[square=olive!30/2 pre VF/from\\
                                          environment]  {Comm};
    % 3. column, from bottom to top
    \node (U)   [square=yellow!30/3 pre W/from\\ yyyyy,
                 right=of Au]                           {St};
    \node (Be)  [square=yellow!30/3 pre W/from\\
                                          zzzzz]        {Be};
    \end{scope}
    % Axes
    \draw [dotted,thick]
        ([xshift=-1mm] Cor.north west) -- ([xshift=-1mm] Cor.west |- Comm.south);
    \draw [dotted,thick]
        ([yshift=-1mm] Sim.south west) -- ([yshift=-1mm] De.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

hopefully is now clear how to how to add missing squares. also you need to check the contents of squares.

Comment: This is great for one quadrant, but I am not sure how to build all the four quadrants with this solution. But it is definitely interesting, I never used chains before.

Comment: for the other quadrant you only nit to change direction of chain grow, all other is symmetric. later i will add this t(for one column) to answer.

Comment: @FedericoGobbo, see edited answer.